# A browser-to-browser live streaming system

Tags: cross-browser, media, live-streaming

I'm trying to put in place a browser-to-browser live streaming website.
So, a foobar user can stream (live) his webcam (video and/or audio) from his webpage (`http://www..example.com/admin/foobar`) and others can receipt the stream on his public webpage (`http://www.example.com/public/foobar`).

What is the simplest solution to do that? How can I do it?

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is the best way to handle the browser-to-browser-communication through a website. It supports audio- and video- live transfer.